# Algorithm similar to bin packing

Tags: algorithm, math, layout, user-interface, grid

I have been experimenting with bin packing algorithms for data visualizations, but none are quite doing what I want to accomplish. Essentially, I am trying to think of an algorithm to represent a set of numbers by a weighted grid.  For example, given a set of numbers [25,25,25,25] you could represent this in a rectangle or square by like this-

[image: four equal part]

However, given a set like this [10,1,1,1], it would look similar to this.

[image: 4 non equal parts]

I am trying to wrap my head around this problem with non-even numbers, and it feels similar to bin packing, but in my case I don't necessarily care about the size of the child objects, I just care about them fitting inside the square or rectangle, and keeping their proportions to the other elements. Does this make sense? The problem seems similar to a the Android UI property weight..

I know it is probably simple, I am just not seeing the forest through the trees..

Comment: Can you be more clear about the constraints? For example, they must be rectangular subregions of a rectangular region of some specified size? That kind of thing.

Comment: It's call Treemapping: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping

Comment: And in case you are using [d3](http://d3js.org/) for your visualization, there is a [Treemap layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout) available.

Comment: oh, so the rectancle area is akin to the total data (25*4 in the first case, 1+1+1+10 in the second) and then each part can be expressed as a quotient? first case: 25/100*rectangle area, second 1/13*rectangle area and 10/13*rectangle area?

Comment: Eugen, maybe you could post your comment as an answer so that we can upvote it and thebringking can accept it. You got there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treemapping is what I was looking for. Thanks Eugen!